# Setting missing values using labelled package across multiple columns?

Tags: r

I am using the `labelled` package and trying to set user-defined missing values. I have a dataframe where I want to set missing values for a list of specific columns rather than the entire dataset.

Currently I have to type out each column (s2 and s3). Is there a more efficient way? My full dataset has dozens of columns.

```
df <- tibble(s1 = c(1, 2, 3, 9), s2 = c(1, 1, 2, 9), s3 = c(1, 1, 2, 9))
df <- df %>% 
  set_na_values(., s2 = 9) %>% 
  set_na_values(., s3 = 9)
na_values(df$s1)
na_values(df$s2)
na_values(df$s3)
```

Comment: The function takes multiple pairs so you don't need to call it more than once - e.g. `df %>%  set_na_values(s2 = 9, s3 = 9)` or if you were dealing with a lot of variables you could programatically build a named vector and splice it inside the function.

Comment: What would the latter look like (named vector and splicing it)?

Comment: For the sake of a simple example, if you wanted to set 9 as a user missing for every column, you could do `df %>%  set_na_values(!!!setNames(rep(9, ncol(.)), names(.)))`.  The trick will be building the vector to apply to only the columns of interest but you'll need to expand your question if you want help in that regard.

Comment: I would want the vector to apply only to s2 and s3, but not s1.

Comment: `nm <- setdiff(names(df), "s1"); df %>% set_na_values(!!!setNames(rep(9, length(nm)), nm))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set_na_values()` function takes multiple pairs so you don't need to call it more than once:

```
library(labelled)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  set_na_values(s2 = 9, s3 = 9)
```

If you were dealing with a lot of variables you could programatically build a named vector or list (if there are multiple missing values per variable) and splice it inside the function.  If, from your comment you wanted to apply it to everything except the `s1` variable, you can do:

```
nm <- setdiff(names(df), "s1")

df %>%
  set_na_values(!!!setNames(rep(9, length(nm)), nm))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
     s1        s2        s3
  <dbl> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>
1     1    1         1     
2     2    1         1     
3     3    2         2     
4     9    9 (NA)    9 (NA)
```

Alternatively, you can use `labelled_spss()` and take advantage of `across()` which allows `tidyselect` semantics (but this will overwrite any existing labelled values):

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(-s1, labelled_spss, na_values = 9))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
     s1        s2        s3
  <dbl> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>
1     1    1         1     
2     2    1         1     
3     3    2         2     
4     9    9 (NA)    9 (NA)
```

To reset any existing values use:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(-s1, ~ labelled_spss(.x, labels = val_labels(.x), na_values = 9)))
```

Comment: I've tested this and it works. Follow-up question: instead of specifying the negative (s1 being the column that I don't want to apply the NA), how would I specify the positive (s2 and s3 are the columns I want to apply the NA) using the named vector approach? @ritchie-sacramento

Comment: You could use something like `setNames(rep(9, 2), paste0("s", 2:3))` - hard to say without more info.